# Can we do the Microsoft Kinect face tracking with two webcams instead of kinect 3d sensor?

Tags: image-processing, kinect, face-recognition

I'm trying to do a face tracking project, so I came to see the microsoft kinect face tracking ,but I don't have a kinect camera,Is it possible to use two webcameras instead of kinect camera.

Comment: With the Kinect SDK? No. But facetracking itself with a video stream is entirely doable. You'd have to develop that yourself though, or look for another available implementation.

Comment: Interesting starting point. This is in C# too http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39060/Face-Detection-in-C

Answer (score 0):

As Bart mentions, the Kinect SDK doesn't have support for two webcams, it's aimed at the Kinect sensor itself only.

You use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) for [stereo calibration](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) but it might worth looking at what you can do with a single camera too. I recommend having a look at [Jason Saragih's Face Tracker](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/FaceTracker) and [Kyle McDonald's ofxFaceTracker addon](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxfacetracker) examples.